# Sidebar getting pushed down

Tags: html, css

My sidebar is getting pushed down instead of staying inline with my `main` class, you can view the issue more in my fiddle. (*This is one of the first times I've not used [bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/) for a project in a very long time*).

view my [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/31rjm8qb/).

Comment: You gave width: 100% to the .main class div, here is a solution for solving this: https://jsfiddle.net/31rjm8qb/8/

Comment: Your HTML doesn't look right. Your div .latest-single is in a .main, which has width: 100%. Your sidebar won't be able to float alongside latest-single with main in the way

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to choose a way of how to display them. (`block`,`flex`,`table`)

i made it working by adding the `display:flex` on `.container` class.

jsfiddle https://jsfiddle.net/31rjm8qb/7/

Answer (score 4):

Instead of `float`, using `flex` is a better approach for responsive design.
Try putting your `sidebar` and `main` inside a `div` with `display` as `flex` and `flex-wrap` as `wrap`.

Here's an example-

```css
.flexbox {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.latest-single {
  width: 70%;
  background-color: blue;
}

.sidebar {
  width: 30%;
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<div class="flexbox">
  <div class="latest-single">
    This is our primary content 
  </div>

  <div class="sidebar">
  This is our sidebar content  
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

You have a couple of problems here.

- `.main` has width 100% so `.sidebar` can not fit
- `.sidebar` is floated while `.main` is not, so they will not line up

I think it would be a good idea to try out `display: flexbox` and remove floats altogether.
Check out the following article: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

Comment: We're trying to make the `.sidebar` inline with our `.main` not our `nav` however, I have fixed this issue and went with the recommendation above yours in adding `display: flex` and it appears my issues are now resolved. Thanks a bunch!

Comment: Misspoke, meant the `sidebar`, edited to correct. :)